# Time series, Graphics showing seasonality but not metrics

Tags: python, time-series, signals

I'm new in time series analysis. And I don't really understand one of my metrics i'm getting.
So, I have data of the utilisation of a feature by a client every day. First, I plotted one signal by month to detect evident seasonality or trend :

[season](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlwk6.png)

AS you can see, we have significant drops each 6-7 days. It corresponds to Saturday and sunday. Which makes totally sense.
When I decompose my time series with seasonal_decompose function, I get this results:

[observed signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16y3S.png)

[trend signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuO8j.png)

[Seasonal signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MAyX.png)

Then, i computed the strength of the trend and seasonality signal. And I got this result:

[Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQFx.png)

Knowing that the metric as the range [0,1]. I'm confused to see the seasonality strength that low.

Am I missing something?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

From the graphs provided, it seems that the model's variance is mostly due to the Remainder component, which is evident in the [observed signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16y3S.png).

Even though you have correctly calculated the component strengths based on [this masterpiece](https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-strength.html) by Rob Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos, the model doesn't seem to fit the data very well.

I would suggest you apply the [Statsmodels STL decomposition](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL) and recalculate the metrics. A simple implementation guide of this algorithm is available [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/different-types-of-time-series-decomposition-396c09f92693).

Comment: Hello Paulo, Thanks for your answer. I applied STL decomposition. And I got these results : Ft : 0.6622086643870505
Fs : 0.45052066151203285. What do you think about this evolution ? Thanks

Comment: Hello Lionbix, I think that this result is already better than the initial one. I think that February was an atypical month in your dataset and it is probably keeping the trend strength at this level, even though the series varies at a very similar rate across the other months. Could you try to [differentiate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) the data or [transform](https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-data-transforms-for-time-series-forecasting/) it and reapply the STL model?

Comment: Hello, i used Pow Transform and got these results : Ft : 0.6250469965180265
Fs : 0.5188509648333105. It's quite better than the first try. I think it will be hard to get a higher seasonality strength. I plotted the signal for each week during each month and we have of course a significant drop during the WE. But during the business days, its quite random.